# How to alphabetically order only a specific column of a a file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a file with the following contents:

**Reduced for readability:**

```
Title,            Author,        Publisher,  Year,  ISBN-10,   ISBN-13
Automate the...,  Al Sweigart,   No Sta...,  2015,  15932...,  978-15932...
Dive into Py...,  Mark Pilgr..., Apress,     2009,  14302...,  978-14302...
"Python Cook...,  "David Bea..., O'Reil...,  2013,  14493...,  978-14493...
Think Python...,  Allen B. D..., O'Reil...,  2015,  14919...,  978-14919...
"Fluent Pyth...,  Luciano Ra..., O'Reil...,  2015,  14919...,  978-14919...
```

**In full:**

```
Title,Author,Publisher,Year,ISBN-10,ISBN-13
Automate the Boring Stuff with Python,Al Sweigart,No Starch Press,2015,1593275994,978-1593275990
Dive into Python 3,Mark Pilgrim,Apress,2009,1430224150,978-1430224150
"Python Cookbook, Third edition","David Beazley, Brian K Jones",O'Reilly Media,2013,1449340377,978-1449340377
Think Python: How to Think Like a Computer Scientist,Allen B. Downey,O'Reilly Media,2015,1491939362,978-1491939369
"Fluent Python: Clear, Concise, and Effective Programming",Luciano Ramalho,O'Reilly Media,2015,1491946008,978-1491946008
```

I want to read the file and write a new file containing these same contents except with the second column (the authors) alphabetically ordered. The header (first row) should not be changed. Any ideas on how to do this? The authors in order should be as follows:

```
Al
Allen
David
Luciano
Mark
```

EDIT: Sorry about not mentioning this but I can't use pandas. Furthermore, all the columns have to be adjusted together BASED on the second column. My bad interpreting this information to you all.

EDIT: I wrote the following function which prints the desired sorting results but does not work when one wants to write the data in a new file:

```
import sys, csv, operator
data = csv.reader(open('books.csv'),delimiter=',')
header = next(data)
print (header)
sortedlist = sorted(data, key=operator.itemgetter(1))
with open("books_sort.csv", "wb") as f:
#          fileWriter = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
           fileWriter = csv.writer(f)
#           fileWriter.writerows(header)
#           fileWriter.writerows(sortedlist)

           for row in sortedlist:
              print (row)
#             f.writerows(row)
```

Comment: I guess the books have been written by the authors in the author column. Now sorting the Author column without changing the Title column don't you think you will have changed the author of the book? eg allen being the second with the book Dive into python 3 yet he wrote think python. Don't you think that's a problem?

Comment: I'm a complete idiot thats how you are supposed to do it. I misread my directions.

Comment: Why can't you use pandas?

Comment: Apparently that would be to easy. I don't see the problem with using the most efficient method but that's what is being said.

Answer (score 3):

Pandas is great for this:

```
important pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv(‘file.csv’, sep=‘,’)
sorted = data.sort_values(by=[‘Author’])
sorted.to_csv(‘outfile.csv’, index=False)
```

Docs for [read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html), [sort_values](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html), [to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)

Comment: Upvoted for inclusion of specific documentation, really helpful!

Comment: Some pointers: `sep=','` may be excluded as it's the default, you can also use `sort_values('Author')`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
sorted = df.sort_values('Author')
sorted.to_csv('result.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

A non `pandas` solution involves reading the text sorting by the second column:

```
import csv
with open('books_and_authors.csv') as f1:
  header, *data = csv.reader(f1)
  with open('books_and_authors.csv', 'w') as f2:
    write = csv.writer(f2)
    write.writerows([header, *sorted(data, key=lambda x:x[1])])
```

Output:

```
Title,Author,Publisher,Year,ISBN-10,ISBN-13
Automate the Boring Stuff with Python,Al Sweigart,No Starch Press,2015,1593275994,978-1593275990
Think Python: How to Think Like a Computer Scientist,Allen B. Downey,O'Reilly Media,2015,1491939362,978-1491939369
"Python Cookbook, Third edition","David Beazley, Brian K Jones",O'Reilly Media,2013,1449340377,978-1449340377
"Fluent Python: Clear, Concise, and Effective Programming",Luciano Ramalho,O'Reilly Media,2015,1491946008,978-1491946008
Dive into Python 3,Mark Pilgrim,Apress,2009,1430224150,978-1430224150
```